# Realization machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

Can you advise me what kind of machine learning to achieve? ... I had thought, for example, to make a face and, by varying the expression through the "manipulate" function (I do not know if it is possible to do so), the machine will tell me if it is sad, happy, etc.
This is the code that allows me to manipulate the face:

```
    Manipulate[
 eyeMat = {{1/(eyeRadius - pupilRadius/2), 0}, {0, 
    1/(0.15 + eyes - pupilRadius/2)}};
 If[Norm[eyeMat.(pup - eyeCenter[[left]])] < 1, 
  pupNow = pup - eyeCenter[[left]];];
 If[Norm[eyeMat.(pup - eyeCenter[[right]])] < 1, 
  pupNow = pup - eyeCenter[[right]];];
 Graphics[{face, eye[left, eyes], eye[right, eyes], Blue, 
   pupil[left, pupNow, eyes], pupil[right, pupNow, eyes], Black, 
   browDraw[left, brows, eyes], browDraw[right, brows, eyes], 
   Inset[mouthDraw[mouth], {0, -0.5}]}, 
  ImageSize -> {400, 450}], {{brows, {-Pi/20, 0}}, {-0.6, 0}, {0.6, 
   0.15}, ControlPlacement -> Left}, {{eyes, 0}, -0.07, 0.07, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider}, {{mouth, 0.15}, -0.401, 0.4, 0.01, 
  ControlPlacement -> Left, 
  ControlType -> VerticalSlider}, {{pup, {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, 
 Initialization :> (face = Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 1.2}]; pupNow = {0, 0};
   left = 1; right = 2;
   eyeRadius = 0.18; eyeCenter = {{-0.4, 0.15}, {0.4, 0.15}};
   pupilRadius = 0.09;
   browUp = 0.25; browW = 0.2; browAng = Pi/20;
   eye[side_, eccen_] := {Black, 
     Circle[eyeCenter[[side]], {eyeRadius + 0.05, eyeRadius + eccen}]};
   pupil[side_, pup_, 
     eccen_] := {Disk[eyeCenter[[side]] + pup + {0, pup[[2]] eccen}, 
      pupilRadius + Max[0, eccen/3]], Black, 
     Disk[eyeCenter[[side]] + pup + {0, pup[[2]] eccen}, 0.03]};
   browDraw[side_, {browAng_, browLift_}, eccen_] := 
    Rotate[{Thickness[0.01], 
      Line[{{eyeCenter[[side]] + {-browW, 
           browLift + browUp + 0.5 eccen}, 
         eyeCenter[[side]] + {browW, 
           browLift + browUp + 0.5 eccen}}}]}, 2 (side - 1.5) browAng];
   mouthDraw[s_] := 
    ParametricPlot[{Cos[u], -s Sin[u]}, {u, Pi/6, Pi - Pi/6}, 
     Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.02]}, 
     PlotRange -> All];)]
```

Now, How can I teach the car to say what kind of expression the face has (sad, happy, etc.)?

Comment: Hey Pasquale, welcome to Mathematica.SE! This is certainly possible, but at the moment your question is too vague. To get meaningful answers you should show what you already tried in code or ask very specific questions what you want to achieve with your code.

Comment: I entered the code

Answer (score 1):

You can try the built-in [facial expression classifier](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/classifier/FacialExpression.html) with Mathematica version 11.3.

**EDIT**
Question was crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1572713), and I provided a very naive solution.

Comment: How can I make a code that allows me to output an image from my computer?

Comment: @Pasquale - Look at the documentation for [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)